# Angular new router: what does it bring to the table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Angular team released a [new router](http://angular.github.io/router/) and I'm trying to understand some motivation.

1. What does it bring to the table compared to ui-router?
2. Does it (or will it) support nested states, views etc (can't see it in the docs)?

Comment: Just to add, not sure about nesting but looks like it supports some form of view composition . Docs suggest we can declare multiple named views like this
`<div router-view-port="name"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing for me is that the Angular team has suggested that we can use the new router to slowly migrate code from Angular 1.x to 2.0 since both versions can use it.

Check out this video from Brian Ford at NGConf 2015 for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vecg70fPDFw&list=PLOETEcp3DkCoNnlhE-7fovYvqwVPrRiY7&index=3